# How can I disable some dates range in a fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to disable days before and after dates range, anybody know how can I do that? (sorry for my english).

Hernan

Comment: There is no feature like this in the calendar. Sorry. YOu will have to process your feed somehow and manually remove them from the feed. How are you getting the dates and from where?

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks! I have to make a calendar for a trip. A user select from/to dates and put events between dates. I want to disable before "from" and after "to" dates. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so you mean on the ACTUAL calendar you don't want people to book certain dates?

Look at this link

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/7MTdn/

Click on a day 15 days later and the alert changes.. something like this? Yea

If that is what you mean i can try and change it for your needs..

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar(
            {
             header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },


                dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) { 
                    var myDate = new Date();

                    //How many days to add from today?
                    var daysToAdd = 15;

                    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + daysToAdd);

                    if (date < myDate) {
                        //TRUE Clicked date smaller than today + daysToadd
                    alert("You cannot book on this day!");    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //FLASE Clicked date larger than today + daysToadd
                        alert("Excellent choice! We can book today..");    
                     }   


            },      

             events: [

                        {
                            title  : 'event2',
                            start  : '2011-03-10',
                            end    : '2011-05-5'
                        }
                    ]
           });
```

*Please note this was written compatible for 1.6.4 and that from version 2+ most of the API has changed and things should be different but the general events and logic should be the same.*

Comment: Update you answer as links to fullcalendar is rotten in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. Updated. I was pulling the source from one off my servers which are offline now. using CDN for 1.6.should last a bit longer. Also added code just incase

Answer (score 1):

In fullCalendar v3 we can use selectConstraint

```
selectConstraint: {
   start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
   end: '2200-01-01'
},
```

if you don't want an event to be droppable in past days you can use

```
eventConstraint: {
  start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  end: '2200-01-01'
},
```