# How to make blocked dates not selectable in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar to add events. Now I'm getting a problem trying to disable certain dates.

For example if I have the following dates: 2017-11-12 , 2017-11-15, 2017-11-18, how can I make these dates not selectable (blocked)?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'event',
            start: new Date(2017, 11, 12)
        },
    ],
});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to block out dates in the Fullcalendar beyond a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670748/how-to-block-out-dates-in-the-fullcalendar-beyond-a-certain-date)

Comment: Check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991941/how-can-i-disable-some-dates-range-in-a-fullcalendar

Comment: Its all about dates range. I'm asking random dates.

Comment: I think your best bet is to use background events to block out these random days, and then when the user is selecting, check the selection doesn't overlap with any of the background events. See the example in the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/ . You can do the same via "eventOverlap" to stop existing events being dragged onto these dates too, if you allow dragging. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238280/allow-eventoverlap-for-background-events-only-in-fullcalendar/46283233#46283233